# WPF copying datagrid converted cell values copies empty string

Tags: c#, wpf

I am not sure if it is bug, or feature, but I am unable to copy Converted value via binding.

I have columns in datagrid:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value.Item}" Header="Položka" />
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value.Quantity}" Header="Množství" />
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value.PrimaryUomCode}" Header="UOM" />
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value.InventoryItemId, Converter={StaticResource InventoryItemIdToItemDescription}, IsAsync=True}" Header="Popis" />
```

if I select cells like this:

[image]

Then only this get copied:

```
184 pc  
50  pc  
7   pc
```

I was unable to solve it, nor find anyone with the same issue.

Does anyone know what is wrong in here?

Just for reference, those are my DG properties:

```
<DataGrid
     x:Name="Stocks_DataGrid"
     AutoGenerateColumns="False"
     IsReadOnly="True"
     SelectionUnit="Cell">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ClipboardContentBinding` property to bind to the same value:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding InventoryItemId, Converter={StaticResource InventoryItemIdToItemDescription}}" 
                    Header="Popis"
                    ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding InventoryItemId, Converter={StaticResource InventoryItemIdToItemDescription}}"/>
```

Comment: Oh god, those years with WPF and I had no clue this property existed. Also, please remove `IsAsync=True` from answer, because with that it doesnt work. I will mark it as answer after you fix it, I am not sure if you would be able to edit that after it is marked

Comment: I just copied your binding. Anyway, now it's removed.

Comment: Well I mean the value displays, but coyping the value with async binding doesnt work